# Socket.io broadcast flag not working (sends data to sender)

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I have following function on my client side, inside `pieces` module:

```
        var nodeCoords = returnCoordinates(node),
        sourceCoords = returnCoordinates(sourceNode),
        board = require('board'),
        player = board.table.cells[sourceCoords.x + 'x' + sourceCoords.y].piece.owner,
        socket = io();

        $(node).css({'border': '2px solid blue', 'width' : '58px', 'height': '58px'});
        $(node).click(function(){

        board.table.cells[sourceCoords.x + 'x' + sourceCoords.y].piece.move(nodeCoords.x, nodeCoords.y);
        board.table.drawPieces();
        board.table.resetBoard();

        socket.emit('move', {'sourceCoords': sourceCoords, 'targetCoords': nodeCoords});
```

What I want to achieve, is to make server send above data to every connected socket, except for sender. So just as various tutorials and [official documentation](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/API.md#flag-broadcast) says, I put following code on server side:

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var port = 8080;
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var players = {

    'white': null,
    'black': null
}

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    app.get('/login', function(req, res){

        if(players.white === null){

            players.white = 'taken';
            res.send('white');
        }else if(players.white !== null && players.black === null){

            players.black = 'taken';
            res.send('black');
            io.emit('login', {msg: 'ready'});
        }else{

            res.send('Two players are currently playing game. Please try later.');
        }
    });

    socket.on('move', function(data){

        socket.broadcast.emit('turnReady', {'sourceCoords': data.sourceCoords, 'targetCoords': data.targetCoords});
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){

        console.log('User disconnected.');
    });
})

http.listen(port, function(){

    console.log('Server is listening on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

On my client side, in main requirejs file, event `'turnReady'` looks like:

```
var socket = io();

$(document).ready(function() {

    var player;

    $.get('/login', function(data, status){

        if(status === 'success'){

            if(data === 'white' || data === 'black'){

                player = data;
            }else{

                alert(data);
            }
        }
    });

    socket.on('login', function(data){

        game(player);
    });

    socket.on('turnReady', function(data){
        console.log('ready! ' + player);
        board.table.cells[data.sourceCoords.x + 'x' + data.sourceCoords.y].piece.move(data.targetCoords.x, data.targetCoords.y);
        board.table.drawPieces();
        board.table.resetBoard();

        board.table.startPlayerTurn(player);
    });
});
```

I used on server side flag `'broadcast'` so I expect that console 'ready' message will appear on every connected client expect for sender. However this isn't true, every client gets above message, even sender. What I did wrong here?

Edit: I provided more code. Thanks to mido comment probably I can think why this is happening. I created another socket object inside pieces module. Is this the reason why broadcast isn't working as it is supposed to? Even if both sockets points at same default namespace?

Comment: can you add an id and check, may be there are two sockets, each is receiving the other's message

Comment: please show us more of your code..

Comment: Updated main question.

Comment: Is `pieces` module required by the main client? I can't see it in the code. Do you create the socket object twice for the same client? Why?

Comment: You create two socket object and everything works fine: one of your object emits `'move'` and the second one receives the broadcast of `'turnReady'` It seems you don't need two of them but one.

Comment: Yes 'pieces' are required by main client. I created second socket inside 'pieces' module, because I can't require main module. I did that because I thought that if I create two instances of sockets pointing at the same default namespace, they should 'act' like the same socket. Now, I understand they do not. Thank you for help!